# Icon Disappeared // Generic rectangle shows up

Tags: windows-7, icons

No clue what happened.

Today, skype just does not have an icon on my screen.

He does have this weird looking emblem.

This is both on the desktop, like this...

[image: Skype Icon On Desktop]

...as well as on the task bar, like this...

[image: Skype Icon On Task Bar]

What did I do this time ?

How do I get it back ?

Comment: Delete the shortcut and create new one.

Comment: rebuild the icon cache: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

Comment: @ElectricRouge  Thanks.  90 seconds, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is to uninstall/reinstall Skype.  It appears you got an update that broke a link to the shortcut's icon data.  This exact thing happened to me just yesterday for a different application.  I rebuilt my shortcuts and now they're back to normal.

Edit:  Uninstalling and Reinstalling nearly any Desktop application (such as Skype) will automatically rebuild the shortcuts for you as part of the install process.

Comment: I've never rebuilt a shortcut.  Can you point me to a tutorial on how to do that ?  //  Edit, just looked on Bing and found some YouTube clips and a couple of forums that purport to teach that.  //  Your advice is still welcome

Comment: I'm sorry,  you *could* rebuild the shortcut manually, but in your case I would suggest uninstalling Skype and Reinstalling it again, this will rebuild the shortcuts for you.

Comment: Will uninstall/reinstall  be simpler than rebuilding the shortcuts ?

Comment: If you haven't rebuilt shortcuts before, I'd say it'd be easier because I'm also thinking if your icons got broken, something else within skype could be broken too, so it's a safe bet to uninstall/reinstall

Comment: Got it.  This will be on today's list of things to do.  Thanks

Comment: You don't **rebuild** a shortcut.  You just create a new shorcut.  How you create a shortcut to a file has remained unchanged for 20 something years.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that shows "rebuilding" and "creating" are different enough words to warrant a discussion?